# How to insert a list of students details in to WP7 Mango database

Tags: linq-to-sql, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I have a list of students: `List<student> std`

How can I insert this list into a WP7 Mango database using LINQ To SQL?

Is there any mechanism present in LINQ To SQL for inserting the entire list to the database table without iterating one by one?

Answer (score 1):

No, you have to insert the records one at a time.